# skip a step in a jQuery multipart form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a standard multipart form...

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal form" id="dsa_form" name="dsa_form">
        <div class="step">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Your Details</legend>
                <div class="form-group"><label for="your_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Name </label></div>
                <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="your_name" class="form-control" id="your_name" placeholder="Full Name" tabindex="1"></div>
                </fieldset>
                </div>
               <div class="step">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Item Details</legend>
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="the_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name of Item *</label></div>
                <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="the_name" class="form-control" id="the_name" placeholder="" tabindex="1"></div>                      
                </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="step">
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>type Required</legend>
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="item_required" class="col-sm-2 control-label">What item do you require (Please select) *</label></div> <div class="col-sm-10"> <select name="item_required" class="form-control" onChange="chgAction()"> <option value="NOT SELECTED" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>  <option value="Full">Full</option> <option value="Half">Half</option>  </select></div>
                <div class="form-group"><label for="item_weight" class="col-sm-2 control-label">weight of item</label></div>
                <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="item_weight" class="form-control" id="item_weight" placeholder="" tabindex="1"></div>
                </fieldset>
                                    </div> 
                 <div class="step">
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>half colour</legend>
                <div class="form-group"><label for="half_colour" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hull/Machinery/Gear/Equipment only</label></div>
                <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="number" name="half_colour" class="form-control qtymath" id="half_colour" placeholder="" tabindex="1"></div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="10pxspacer">&nbsp;</div>  
                </div> 
                <div class="step">
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>Questionnaire</legend>
                <div class="form-group"><label for="ssqone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">what do you need the item for?</label></div>
                <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="ssqone" class="form-control" id="ssqone" placeholder="" tabindex="1"></div>
                </fieldset>
                 </div> 
                <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="action btn-sky text-capitalize back btn">Back</button>
                <button type="button" class="action btn-sky text-capitalize next btn">Next</button>
                <button type="submit" class="action btn-hot text-capitalize submit btn generalBut">Request Item</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
  </div> 
            </form>
```

And I'm using jQuery to navigate around the form - all works fine, but i'm trying to skip a step based on a menu selected option

```
item_required
```

I using the function: function chgAction() which updates the 'current' var all well and good, but the form does not skip a step, the var changes, but its as if the next button is not picking up the change in the 'current' var.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var current = 1;
    widget      = $(".step");
    btnnext     = $(".next");
    btnback     = $(".back"); 
    btnsubmit   = $(".submit");
    widget.not(':eq(0)').hide();
    hideButtons(current);
    setProgress(current);
    btnnext.click(function(){
        if(current < widget.length){
            if($(".form").valid()){
                widget.show();
                widget.not(':eq('+(current++)+')').hide();
                setProgress(current);
            }
        }
        hideButtons(current);
    })
    btnback.click(function(){
        if(current > 1){
            current = current - 2;
            if(current < widget.length){
                widget.show();
                widget.not(':eq('+(current++)+')').hide();
                setProgress(current);
            }
        }
        hideButtons(current);
    })
    $('.form').validate({ 
        ignore:":not(:visible)",            
        rules: {
            your_name     : "required",
        },
    });
});
setProgress = function(currstep){
    var percent = parseFloat(100 / widget.length) * currstep;
    percent = percent.toFixed();
    $(".progress-bar").css("width",percent+"%").html(percent+"%");      
}
hideButtons = function(current){
    var limit = parseInt(widget.length); 
    $(".action").hide();
    if(current < limit) btnnext.show();
    if(current > 1) btnback.show();
    if (current == limit) { 
        $(".display label:not(.control-label)").each(function(){
            console.log($(this).find("label:not(.control-label)").html($("#"+$(this).data("id")).val()));   
        });
        btnnext.hide(); 
        btnsubmit.show();
    }
}
function chgAction() {
var form = document.dsa_form;
console.log('chgAction()');
console.log(form.item_required.selectedIndex);
switch (form.item_required.selectedIndex) {
    case 1:
        current = current;
        break;
    case 2:
        current = 5;
        setProgress(5);
        widget = widget+1;
        break;
}
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = current;
```

}

I'm using jquery-1.11.2, any pointers would be of great use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have now sorted this. Instead of using a onClcik on the form select, I removed that function, and added an if statement based on the the menu select, on to the buttons. Now works a treat. so the finished javascript code is as follows...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = document.dsa_form;
    var current = 1;
    widget      = $(".step");
    btnnext     = $(".next");
    btnback     = $(".back"); 
    btnsubmit   = $(".submit");
    widget.not(':eq(0)').hide();
    hideButtons(current);
    setProgress(current);
    btnnext.click(function(){
        if(form.item_required.selectedIndex == 2  && current == 3) {
            current = current+1;
        if(current < widget.length){
            // Check validation
            if($(".form").valid()){
                widget.show();
                widget.not(':eq('+(current++)+')').hide();
                setProgress(current +1);
            }
        }
        hideButtons(current);
        } else {
        if(current < widget.length){
            // Check validation
            if($(".form").valid()){
                widget.show();
                widget.not(':eq('+(current++)+')').hide();
                setProgress(current);
            }
        }
        hideButtons(current);
    }
    })
    btnback.click(function(){
    if(form.item_required.selectedIndex == 2  && current == 5) {
            if(current > 1){
            current = current - 3;
            if(current < widget.length){
                widget.show();
                widget.not(':eq('+(current++)+')').hide();
                setProgress(current -1);
            }
        }
        hideButtons(current);
        } else {
        if(current > 1){
            current = current - 2;
            if(current < widget.length){
                widget.show();
                widget.not(':eq('+(current++)+')').hide();
                setProgress(current);
            }
        }
        hideButtons(current);
    }   
    })
    $('.form').validate({ // initialize plugin
        ignore:":not(:visible)",            
        rules: {
        your_name     : "required",
        },
    });
});
setProgress = function(currstep){
    var percent = parseFloat(100 / widget.length) * currstep;
    percent = percent.toFixed();
    $(".progress-bar").css("width",percent+"%").html(percent+"%");      
}
hideButtons = function(current){
    var limit = parseInt(widget.length);
    $(".action").hide();
    if(current < limit) btnnext.show();
    if(current > 1) btnback.show();
    if (current == limit) { 
        $(".display label:not(.control-label)").each(function(){
            console.log($(this).find("label:not(.control-label)").html($("#"+$(this).data("id")).val()));   
        });
        btnnext.hide(); 
        btnsubmit.show();
    }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = current;
}
```

Now works a treat.